# How get method body offset from Java .class file

Tags: java, class, bytecode

How find on a Java .class file where start the method body

Ex.

```
package com.test;

class Hello
{

    public static boolean isTrue()  {
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }
}
```

I want know where start `isTrue()` method body on Hello.class

I can find 04 0C (bytecode: iconst_1 ireturn ) with a hexeditor at address 0x0205 but I want this value programmatically for any method by name.

Comment: The class file format is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: I know @Perception but this requiere a complete parser. I read a post of someone who modify ASM classes but not post any code.

Answer (score 1):

In the JVM classfile format, offsets aren't stored to particular sections. Instead, each item has its own length, and it is parsed sequentially. This means that in order to find the method code, you'll at the very least have to be able to parse the constant pool to get each type and calculate string lengths, as methods come after the constant pool.

At that point you might as well use a fully featured classfile parser. There are quite a few libraries out there.

P.S. At the bytecode level, methods are not identified uniquely by name, but by (name, descriptor) pairs. Multiple methods can have the same name. The same goes for fields.

Comment: Tested with ASM and Javassist without luck. Maybe ej jclasslib is the solution but can´t not pick a simple code example.

Comment: Tested on the fly method rewrite with ASM. Loaded Hello.class and the change isTrue() to return false. But I can´t know where isTrue() body is locate on class file. Not failed, just not what needed.